Apache Camel Route Not Pulling Files From FTP
I've written a simple route in XML DSL using Apache Camel (ver: camel-core-2.25.4, camel-ftp-2.25.4) where I want to pull files from a FTP location. But it is not fetching any file from the FTP location. And it does not show any error. Below is the XML DSL part. Deployed in Tomcat 9.0.85. Java version used 1.8. what to do?
<route id="routeGhatalFTP1">            
    <from uri="ftp://jayanta@XX.XX.XXX.XXX:NNNN//NPCIPMTPACS//GPCB//test?password=XXXXXXXXX&amp;delete=true"/> 
     <log message="APBS FTP FILE PROCESSING : [${body}]" />
    <to uri="file:C:\\Deployments\\GPCB\ChannelPath\\NPCIPMT\\testfile?noop=true"/>           
</route>

I want to fetch the files in local system and process thereafter. Other routes are working but this route is not working where I am trying to fetch files from specific FTP location.

It can be passive vs active mode, see camel-ftp docs
